# Unable to connect yugabytedb docker container with sonarqube container using docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, sonarqube, yugabytedb

I am using Sonarqube for the code quality check for a while. Using Postgres at the backend. But now our team want to use yugabytedb but i am finding it hard to connect to  yugabytedb. I tried manually deploying separate containers of sonarqube and yugabytedb but failed to connect with each other.Below is the docker-compose.yaml file that i have used previously for postgres-sonarqube. How do i edit this yaml to convert it to postgres-yugabytedb?

```
version: "3"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:6.7.1
    container_name: sonarqube
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=password123
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonarqube
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

  db:
    image: postgres:10.1
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password123
      - POSTGRES_DB=sonarqube
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_db:/var/lib/postgresql10
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql10/data

volumes:
  postgresql_data:
  sonarqube_bundled-plugins:
  sonarqube_conf:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_db:
  sonarqube_extensions:
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of docker-compose that has the same behavior of yours, using the environment variables to create the database and user:
https://dev.to/franckpachot/docker-composeyaml-to-start-yugabytedb-with-postgresuser-postgrespassword-postgresdb-env-4do3